# PhpMyAdmin like table (resize and rearrange cells)

Tags: html, html-table, resize

I was wondering if it is possible to (easily) reproduce the resizing and rearranging of tablecells found in the phpmyadmin table (I mean the html table where the database values are shown).
Actually I  guess any solution would do, but since phpmyadmin is open source I was thinking that it perhaps I could rely on their code.

EDIT: what I would like to do is the following. Let's say in my html table I have four visible cols: Name, Last Name, Place of Birth and Birthday.

Let's say that, by default, those are arranged in that order, and each column has a width of 25%.

I would like to give users the possibility to rearrange the table html table so that they can choose the preferred order, and width, of each column.

I'm wondering if it is possibile to do so simply working with the DOM (basically I'd say with js), or if the only way is to combine js, ajax and php, which, however, would result in a much more complex code.

Comment: why would you want to rearrange the way phpadmin displays your tables.  Change the order of them within your table, else this can cause confusion later.

Comment: I've added a briex explaination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use a jQuery-library like "[Flexigrid](http://flexigrid.info)" as this has everything you need:

- sortable columns
- hide/show columns
- change column widths
- ajax support
- an API you could connect with